# Average on datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have the following table with a datetime column:

```
id | datetime 
1  | 2014-12-01 20:00:00
2  | 2014-12-03 12:04:00
3  | 2014-12-04 10:15:00
4  | 2014-12-05 13:45:00
.. | ...etc
```

First I select only the hour & minute of the datetime field, but I don't know how to select the average on a time field:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i') as time FROM table_x;
```

The end result should be the average time in HH:SS format.

Comment: you can't average a formatted time value. it's a string. What's the result of `average('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't make sense. Here's why.

*Average*, in the sense of the arithmetic mean, is calculated by dividing the *sum of the values* by the number of values. What's the sum of '2014-01-01 08:00 am' and '2014-01-01 09:00 am'? This is *literally* nonsense; you can't add 9:00 am to 8:00 am.

Both the median and the mode make sense as a measurement of central tendency for values of type DateTime. But average does not.

Other platforms with better type support make it clearer. Take PostgreSQL, for example.

```
sandbox=# create table test (ts timestamp with time zone);
CREATE TABLE
sandbox=# insert into test values ('2014-01-01 08:00');
INSERT 0 1
sandbox=# insert into test values ('2014-01-01 09:00');
INSERT 0 1
sandbox=# select avg(ts) from test;
ERROR:  function avg(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: select avg(ts) from test;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
sandbox=# select sum(ts) from test;
ERROR:  function sum(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: select sum(ts) from test;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Often, people using MySQL are trying to express a time interval using a DateTime data type. This can be confusing, because both intervals and points in time use similar notation. For example, the value '08:00' might mean "eight hours" if you interpret it as an interval. It might mean "eight o'clock am" if you interpret it as a point in time.

MySQL supports point-in-time data types. It does *not* support SQL intervals. But PostgreSQL does, and here's how it differs.

```
sandbox=# create table test (duration interval);
CREATE TABLE
sandbox=# insert into test values ('15 hours');
INSERT 0 1
sandbox=# insert into test values ('16 hours');
INSERT 0 1
sandbox=# select sum(duration) from test;
   sum
----------
 31:00:00
(1 row)

sandbox=# select avg(duration) from test;
   avg
----------
 15:30:00
(1 row)
```

The distinction: while it doesn't make sense to add or average 8 o'clock and 9 o'clock, it *does* make sense to add and average 8 hours and 9 hours.

If you want to store something *like* SQL intervals in MySQL, store them as integers meaning minutes or seconds (or whatever), and do arithmetic on the integers.

Comment: MySQL **does** support time interval, check [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) field type.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the average with an expression like this:

```
select avg(time_to_sec(time(datetime)))
```

To get back to a time:

```
select sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(time(datetime))))
```

You can then format this however you like.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Maybe the OP still needs DATE part of the DATETIME field, and currently just needs the time average. And this is the solution.

Comment: @Glavić . . . I also don't understand why the OP did not accept this answer.  I'm pretty sure it works as written in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average date only:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(datefield AS INT)) AS DATETIME) FROM dates;
```

If you also want the time:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(datefield AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) FROM dates;
```